# Dropdownlist returning null viewdata Id in partialview

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, ajax.beginform

I am working on a multi-step form which must commit the first step to database before the other steps  add up and commit finally after last step. Looking at the options I decided to use sessions(however I will be happy to use any better alternative).  I managed to get this to work and later decided to use ajax for the form submission hence the requirement of partialviews.  The problem is the dropdowns are returning null viewdata  values - ie they are not binding.  Can anyone suggest the best way to compose in the controller to make this work. It works fine if I revert to return views instead of return partialviews.

Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous] 
public ActionResult ContactViewDetails()
         {
ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(db.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
             return PartialView("ContactViewDetails");
}
```

model

```
 public int CountryId{get;set;}
  public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
  .......and others
```

Default Page View

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<div id="divContainer"> 
     @Html.Partial("RegViewDetails")
 </div>
```

PartialView:  ContactViewDetails.cs

```
@{
AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
options.HttpMethod = "POST";
options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;
options.UpdateTargetId = "divContainer";
}
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactViewDetails", "OnlineApplication", options, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryList, new { @class = "chooseOption" })
 @Html.......others
 }
```

The ContactViewDetails page is the second step in the form succession The first step is RegViewDetails page as you can see in the Default page view. After validation RegViewDetails returns ContactViewDetails Partial

```
......
return PartialView("ContactViewDetails");
```

Comment: Never give the `SelectList` property the same name as the property your binding to. `ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(..)` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CountryList, ...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks I have changed that but still not binding

Comment: You have mentioned a partial view - is this dropdown being rendered in a partial (and if so do you pass the HtmlFieldPrefix). You need to give some more code to understand were the problem may be.

Comment: what are you buying by submitting the form by ajax?

Comment: @Qudoos  thanks for the question seeking clarification- I am using Ajax for better user experience.  But I managed to fix the problem that was the only stumbling block.